# How do I separate Interleaved sentences using LSTM networks?

Tags: tensorflow, word2vec, lstm, sequence

I have a problem statement wherein the following input

*The* **James** *world* **Bond** *shall* **can't** *end* **save us** *tomorrow.*

must be converted into this -

*The world shall end tomorrow*

&

**James Bond can't save us**

Essentially my inputs are a set of sentences interleaved with each other, and I need to separate them.

My training data contains slight variations of these interleaving sentences, I have been trying to work with a 1024 cell 2 Layered LSTM network, currently achieving about 65% accuracy when trying to predict the next word given the current set of words. I use the prediction from this model to chain words together into distinct sentences.

The questions that I have are

1. Is LSTM RNN the best way to achieve something like this?
2. What should be a good LSTM Cell size? (I have a vocab of about 22K words.)
3. Are 2 layers sufficient for modeling this problem statement?